# replace function on Pipeline resource variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Follow the [azure online document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace) and [Pipeline resource variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline-resource-variables) I'd like to get the branch name from another pipeline, and use function `replace()` to get the real branch name.

```
variables:
- name: branchName
  value: $[replace(variables[resources.pipeline.mypipeline.sourceBranch], 'refs/heads/', '')]
```

but it always failed to pass the pipeline syntax check

Comment: please provide the error message, if there is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the following code and it's working.

Ensure you wrap the var in single quotes e.g: `` variables[`resources.pipeline.mypipeline.sourceBranch`] ``

And that you have defined a `resources:` block pointing to your pipeline.

```
pool: default

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: james
    source: james

variables:
- name: branchName
  value: $[replace(variables['resources.pipeline.james.sourceBranch'], 'ref', 'YEAHBUDDY')]

stages:
  - stage: approval_check
    jobs:
    - job: bash
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            # Write your commands here
            set -x
            echo $(branchName)
```

Bash Output:

`echo YEAHBUDDYs/heads/main`

Comment: Looks promise, let me test it